# Problems caused by android studio 3.0 update or bad code?

Tags: java, android, string

I try to run the following code, but android studio keeps saying there are problems with saving string objects, but as far as I know the code was written correctly. Can anyone see where the problem is and help me fix it?
I have way more problems with the android studio after the latest update, so I have difficulty figuring out whether the problems are due to my code being wrong somewhere or the update.

> Error:(90, 37) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(CityWeatherData,Class) constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable (argument mismatch; CityWeatherData cannot be converted to String) constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class) is not applicable (argument mismatch; CityWeatherData cannot be converted to Context)
>
> Error:(95, 13) error: cannot find symbol method startActivity(Intent)
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

I have a class that gets data from OpenWeatherMap as JSON objects and displays them in an Activity.

Non-activity class:

```
public class CityWeatherData extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result = ""; //JSON data will be kept here when first downloaded
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        //API set up in OpenWeatherMap
        //Try and catch used in case user does not have internet connection etc.
        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream input = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            //Reader to read inputStream for URL
            InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(input);

            int data = inputReader.read(); //Data from stream is put into an int called data

            //When data finishes reading = -1 ; There for while loop need for data not equal to -1
            while (data != -1){

                char current = (char) data;
                result += current;
                data = inputReader.read();
            }

            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        //Create JSON object from result
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONObject weatherData = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("main"));
            //The data we are interesed in is located after "main"

            //Get temp from main
            double temp = Double.parseDouble(weatherData.getString("temp"));

            //Temp is given i Kelvin so it needs to be converted to Celcius
            int tempInt = (int) (temp -273.15);

            //Get city name
            String placeName = jsonObject.getString("name");

            //Get description
            String weatherDescription = jsonObject.getString("description");

            //Get humidity
            double humidityValue = Double.parseDouble(weatherData.getString("humidity"));

            Intent sendDataIntent = new Intent(CityWeatherData.this, CityDetailsActivity.class);
            sendDataIntent.putExtra("tempData", tempInt);
            sendDataIntent.putExtra("cityNameData", placeName);
            sendDataIntent.putExtra("humidityData", humidityValue);
            sendDataIntent.putExtra("descriptionData", weatherDescription);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Activity class:

```
public class CityDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String placeName;
    int tempInt;
    double humidityValue;
    String weatherDescription;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_city_details);

        Bundle getData = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (getData !=null){
            int tempInt = getData.getInt("tempData");
            String placeName = getData.getString("cityNameData");
            double humidityValue = getData.getDouble("humidityData");
            String weatherDescription = getData.getString("descriptionData");

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Update with info from ShowData
        updateFields();
    }

    private void updateFields(){
        // Used to show data
        TextView city_name = findViewById(R.id.city_name);
        city_name.setText(placeName);
        TextView temp = findViewById(R.id.temp);
        temp.setText(String.valueOf(tempInt));
        TextView humidity = findViewById(R.id.humidity);
        humidity.setText(String.valueOf(humidityValue));
        TextView show_description = findViewById(R.id.show_description);
        show_description.setText(weatherDescription);
    }

    //Save current data in activity upon rotation
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Comment: What problems? Where? Please be specific in your description.

Comment: what does `problems with saving string objects` mean? What is the error message?

Comment: post the exact error code

Comment: Error:(90, 37) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(CityWeatherData,Class<CityDetailsActivity>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; CityWeatherData cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; CityWeatherData cannot be converted to Context)

Comment: Error:(95, 13) error: cannot find symbol method startActivity(Intent)

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AsyncTask` is taking in parameters without actually launching the activity.

**Edit:** Using weak reference for activity context.

```
private static class CityWeatherData extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

        private WeakReference<MainActivity> mainActivity;    

        public CityWeatherData(MainActivity context) {   
            mainActivity = new WeakReference<>(context);            
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
          ....
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            MainActivity cxt = mainActivity.get();
            if (cxt != null) {

            //Create JSON object from result
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONObject weatherData = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("main"));
            //The data we are interesed in is located after "main"

            //Get temp from main
            double temp = Double.parseDouble(weatherData.getString("temp"));

            //Temp is given i Kelvin so it needs to be converted to Celcius
            int tempInt = (int) (temp -273.15);

            //Get city name
            String placeName = jsonObject.getString("name");

            //Get description
            String weatherDescription = jsonObject.getString("description");

            //Get humidity
            double humidityValue = Double.parseDouble(weatherData.getString("humidity"));

            Intent sendDataIntent = new Intent(cxt, CityDetailsActivity.class);
            sendDataIntent.putExtra("tempData", tempInt);
            sendDataIntent.putExtra("cityNameData", placeName);
            sendDataIntent.putExtra("humidityData", humidityValue);
            sendDataIntent.putExtra("descriptionData", weatherDescription);
            startActivity(sendDataIntent);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: ah yes! Thnx! That one I missed :)

Comment: Accept the answer if it fixes the question asked.

Comment: Your error is that your using `context` of your activity in AsyncTask. Always utilize a weak reference to the activity to always ensure it is garbage collected. I will update my answer.

Comment: This answered my question....I can not find the plave where I accept the answer though xD